# Может в однотипных предложениях междометие "ну" то отделяться запятой, то нет?

Tags: пунктуация, междометие, частицы

Может, моё "ну" и не междометие, частицы с междометиями чередуются, но вот то хочу запятую, то дудки.

> У меня есть знакомый, он как-то психанул и пересёк океан с Конюховым.
>   И так они удачно шли по маршруту Колумба, когда он открывает Америку,
>   так всё у них удачно складывалось, что герою стало скучно: **ну,
>   приключение уже подходит к концу, ну, ничего особенного. Ну ничего не
>   происходит, ну идут как Колумб, ну да, под парусами,** вот он и спросил:
>   «А когда уже буря будет?» Рассказывает, что великий путешественник
>   впал в страшную ярость и закричал: «А теперь молись!!!»

А запятая перед "и молиться" как? просится, зараза, напрашивается.

> И действительно – **не прошло и часа, как пришлось потрудиться и молиться,
>   говорит, пришлось тоже.** Вспомнила я эту историю и подумала: хотела –
>   на тебе. Ведь есть у меня ещё один знакомый, который периодически
>   покачивается в своём небоскребе. Но ведь мы в новом мире живем – новые
>   технологии.

И как обрамлять Японию?

> **Там, где он – в Японии, – там** все учтено. Не страшно.

---

Не дроблю на три вопроса, потому что всё составляет контекст всего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня есть знакомый, он как-то психанул и пересёк океан с Конюховым. И так они удачно шли по маршруту Колумба, когда он открывает Америку, так всё у них хорошо складывалось, что герою стало **скучно. Приключение уже подходит к концу – и ничего особенного. Ну ничего не происходит: ну идут как Колумб, ну да, под парусами, вот он и спросил: «А когда же буря будет?»** Рассказывает, что великий путешественник впал в страшную ярость и закричал: «А теперь молись!!!»

И действительно – **не прошло и часа, как пришлось потрудиться, и молиться, говорит, тоже пришлось.** Вспомнила я эту историю и подумала: хотела – на тебе. Ведь есть у меня ещё один знакомый, который периодически покачивается в своём небоскребе. **Но ведь мы-то в новом мире живем – другие технологии. Там, где он, в Японии, – там все учтено.** Не страшно.

**Пояснение**

1) Текст исправлен так, чтобы легко читалось. Ненужные повторы убраны.

Думаю, что здесь вообще **нет междометия НУ (с запятой) со значением побуждения или выражением чувства удивления,** только усилительная частица НУ (без запятой).

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_501

2) Запятая поставлена: нет однородных отношений, разная структура предложений, наличие собственных распространителей.

3) Тире относится к структуре предложения (не к Японии). Повтор слова ***там***.

Comment: А-а, хитрррая! Мне вот это надо сохранить без убираний: ***...герою стало скучно: ну, приключение уже подходит к концу, ну, ничего особенного.***  Кроме "легко читалось", нужно, чтобы автор узнавал свою интонацию. А то про некоторые приглаженные места говорит: как подстрочник какой.

Comment: Понятно...Тогда надо еще поработать с текстом.

Comment: Из письма: ***...и я предлагаю взять нам правку Шарончика - все правильно! именно этого и хотелось, просто переборщила с "разговорным" :)***

Comment: Это про меня? Спасибо, очень приятно! Я как школьник, получивший пятерку.